# How to configure Fedora 34 with three NICs and three subnets to route traffic?

Tags: linux, fedora, subnet, route, interface

I have a Fedora 34 linux and it has a physical ethernet interface (**NIC3**), a physical wifi interface (**NIC2**) and an USB/Ethernet interface (**NIC1**) (USB LTE Dongle).
I would like to use the NIC3 to route all traffic to NIC1. And I would like to keep the NIC2 as management interface that reach the Linux machine. That is all.
[block scheme of the plan - click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6TKc.jpg)

```
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.8.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s29f7u5
0.0.0.0         192.168.99.254  0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp16s0
0.0.0.0         192.168.55.10   0.0.0.0         UG    20101  0        0 ens1
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s29f7u5
192.168.55.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 ens1
192.168.99.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp16s0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0

[root@thanos ~]# ip route show
default via 192.168.8.1 dev enp0s29f7u5 proto dhcp metric 100
default via 192.168.99.254 dev wlp16s0 proto dhcp metric 600
default via 192.168.55.10 dev ens1 proto static metric 20101
192.168.8.0/24 dev enp0s29f7u5 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.8.127 metric 100
192.168.55.0/24 dev ens1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.55.10 metric 101
192.168.99.0/24 dev wlp16s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.99.142 metric 600
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown

enp0s29f7u5: connected to Wired connection 2
        "Huawei E353/E3131"
        ethernet (cdc_ether), 00:1E:10:1F:00:00, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default, ip6 default
        inet4 192.168.8.127/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        route4 192.168.8.0/24
        inet6 2a00:1110:209:1c4:763d:4da5:c8cf:5778/64
        inet6 2a00:1110:222:5201:5ff0:45bc:f54b:d523/64
        inet6 2a00:1110:209:1c4:10:2030:4050:2/128
        inet6 fe80::1c5e:de37:2e84:8fee/64
        route6 2a00:1110:222:5201::/64
        route6 2a00:1110:209:1c4::/64
        route6 ::/0
        route6 2a00:1110:209:1c4:10:2030:4050:2/128
        route6 fe80::/64

wlp16s0: connected to SB25
        "Intel PRO/Wireless 3945ABG"
        wifi (iwl3945), 00:1F:3C:87:2D:DE, hw, mtu 1500
        inet4 192.168.99.142/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        route4 192.168.99.0/24
        inet6 fe80::ce52:130a:ec8a:39db/64
        route6 fe80::/64
        route6 ::/0

virbr0: connected (externally) to virbr0
        "virbr0"
        bridge, 52:54:00:60:80:14, sw, mtu 1500
        inet4 192.168.122.1/24
        route4 192.168.122.0/24

ens1: connected to System ens1
        "Broadcom and subsidiaries NetLink BCM5787M"
        ethernet (tg3), 00:1F:29:9D:A2:64, hw, mtu 1500
        inet4 192.168.55.10/24
        route4 192.168.55.0/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
```

EDIT1: (Additional Information)
Forward is enabled
Iptables is disabled

```
[root@thanos ~]# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
[root@thanos ~]# systemctl status iptables.service
○ iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2021-09-06 13:46:59 CEST; 57min ago
    Process: 2043 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2119 ExecStop=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2043 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 67ms

Sep 06 13:45:54 thanos systemd[1]: Starting IPv4 firewall with iptables...
Sep 06 13:45:54 thanos iptables.init[2043]: iptables: Applying firewall rules: [  OK  ]
Sep 06 13:45:54 thanos systemd[1]: Finished IPv4 firewall with iptables.
Sep 06 13:46:59 thanos systemd[1]: Stopping IPv4 firewall with iptables...
Sep 06 13:46:59 thanos iptables.init[2119]: iptables: Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: filter [  OK  ]
Sep 06 13:46:59 thanos iptables.init[2119]: iptables: Flushing firewall rules: [  OK  ]
Sep 06 13:46:59 thanos systemd[1]: iptables.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 06 13:46:59 thanos systemd[1]: Stopped IPv4 firewall with iptables.
```

Comment: Which of these interfaces is supposed to provide access to the Internet?

Comment: Hi Michael! NIC1 (enp0s29f7u5).

Comment: That's strange. You have given gateway addresses to all three of them, as if you intended to use all three to access the Internet. Only the device providing Internet should have a gateway.

Comment: The USB LTE Dongle creates an Ethernet interface (NIC1) and configures it automatically. This is y it has GW address.  NIC2 is a wifi ethernet. This connects to that network from where I can manage the linux via SSH. It is on DHCP. And the third interface is the physical internal interface of the computer (NIC3). GW has just been added manually because I had no any better idea.

Comment: I have no clue why it is not working. I give it up...